# Update Database field value by Alphabetical order

Tags: mysql

Reorder rows

A row in my database it in a random order with the following characters

HFMNLBX#&I

It was input weirdly and the rows are like HF and FH, which are both equivalent to the system. Is there a way to update all of the rows to go in alphabetical order, then the characters on the end?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this one helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427208/sorting-string-characters-in-mysql

Comment: What is your current MySQL query?

Comment: I don't have a query yet. I want to set the rows to alphabetical order such as HML will become HLM, XB will become BX, and so on

Comment: So, the title is a bit of a misnomer: you don't want to order the row, you want to order the characters in the field?

Comment: @Wrikken Yeah, sorry for that. I want to update the current field to be in alphabetical order

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427208/sorting-string-characters-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to alphabetize the characters in a column:

```
select concat((case when col like '%A%' then 'A' else '' end),
              (case when col like '%B%' then 'B' else '' end),
              . . .
              (case when col like '%Z%' then 'Z' else '' end)
             ) as newcol
from t
```

Note that this does not handle duplicate letters.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "characters on the end".  You can use a subquery, for instance, to handle just a subset of them.

Or, if you want to keep everything after the `#`, something like:

```
select concat((case when col like '%A%#%' then 'A' else '' end),
              (case when col like '%B%#%' then 'B' else '' end),
              . . .
              (case when col like '%Z%#%' then 'Z' else '' end),
              substring(col, locate('#', col) - 1)
             ) as newcol
from t
```

Comment: A sidenote: this will remove any non-alphabetic characters like "#" or "!", I guess the question starter wants them at the end (but it is hard to understand)

Comment: @nicogawenda . . . The first query will.  The second keeps everything after a `#`.

Comment: Ah ok it is sure that the non-alpha stuff is prepended by #, cool solution then:)