# mysql alphabetical order applied to a string

Tags: mysql

Is it a way in mysql to alphabetically ordering a string ?
I am looking for a function who does that :

```
select alphabeticallyorder('cba')
```

will return me

```
'abc'
```

Comment: Look into SQL user-defined functions.... you'd probably be better off doing this before throwing the data at a query though. Also, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427208/sorting-string-characters-in-mysql) which asks a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

A query like this should return the values that you need. I know it's not a nice query, and you also need a numbers table, filled with numbers:

```
SELECT col, GROUP_CONCAT(SUBSTRING(col, n, 1)
                         ORDER BY SUBSTRING(col, n, 1)
                         SEPARATOR '') AS ordered_col
FROM
  tablename INNER JOIN numbers
  ON LENGTH(tablename.col)>=numbers.n
GROUP BY
  id, col
```

Also it will work only if `LENGTH(col)=CHAR_LENGTH(col)`. Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5104f1/3).

Answer (score -1):

Please see the REVERSE function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse

```
mysql> SELECT REVERSE('abc');
    -> 'cba'
```

Comment: what will be if an argument is `'bac'` ?