# Is Value sorting possible in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

**Example:**

If I have a database table named `products` and a column within named `product_title`

**contents under `product_title`**

```
zyx
cba
defabc
```

**What I require?**

```
`zyx` should be changed `xyz`
`cba` should be changed `abc`
`defabc` should be changed `abcdef`
```

All values in alphabetical order.

**What I tried?**

I tried searching for the requirement, but I couldn't find any solution for it. I just want to know **"is this possible"**?

**if this is not possible**, how can i sort my records with most matched substring?

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding.  Are you wanting to `update` the data -- `update table set field = 'xyz' where field = 'zyx'`?

Comment: Try this function - Reverse()
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Comment: not exactly @sgeddes, can't we cast the field temporarily to sort in alphabetical order?

Comment: I believe the OP is asking if MySQL is able to sort the values string literal alphabetically after selection. @ameenulla0007 please confirm that is what you want.

Comment: yup exactly, @Pheagey. i just wanna have temporary sorting of field values for comparison under condition..

Comment: Why do you need to sort the contents of the columns alphabetically? You wouldn't be storing more than one piece of data in a column, would you?

Comment: YEa.. `Reverse()` isn't going to work for that one. There is interesting answer (the second one) [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232979/mysql-alphabetical-order-applied-to-a-string), with a "Numbers" table and some `substring()` sneakery that looks promising (haven't tried it myself).

Comment: the idea is to get exact INDEX of the substring, through which i can utilize `LOCATE` function in order to list out most matching records.

Comment: Because there is no split functionality in MYSQL it will be complicated.

Comment: then how to get most matched substring, find the finest index and sort it accordingly? @maraca

Comment: If you want to use stored procedures it could be done. E.g. if you don't care about performance you can implement a bubble sort with substring and reverse ;-)

Comment: :D cool, but most importantly i don't wanna lose performance here. but i can have stored procedures, there is no issue with it..

Comment: is the number of choices limited to a managable amount? Like a-f and x-z?

Comment: No there is no limitation here, as the table contains product info, product title would be anything.

Comment: I'm asking because you could count how many times one specific character appears in a string by doing the following (for example 'A' in String s): length(s) - length(replace('A', '', s))

Comment: But, doesn't this lower down the performance? Because it can also be lengthier string to check.

Comment: It might be best if you posed your actual question/requirement. If you're dealing with product names then this doesn't make any sense. If I search for "desserts" I don't want to find "stressed".

Comment: @ameenulla0007 I think the best best is to return the select results, then use a logic language to sort the array/object/collection of results by the alphabetical values. Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912469/php-how-to-sort-the-characters-in-a-string

Comment: @pheagey if I limit down SQL records to 3, then the most matched string record would not be available in the result.

Answer (score 1):

there is no build-in function to sort symbols in string in mysql.

anyway you can create your own stored procedure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sv(
    x VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    declare r varchar(255);
    declare maxlen int;
    declare pos int;
    declare sym char(1);
    declare npos int;

    set r = "";

    set maxlen = length(x);
    set pos = 1;
    while (pos <= maxlen) do
        set sym = substr(x, pos, 1);

        set npos = 1;
        while ((npos <= length(r)) and (substr(r, npos, 1) < sym)) do
            set npos = npos + 1;
        end while;
        set r = concat(substr(r, 1, npos-1), sym, substr(r, npos));

        set pos = pos + 1;
    END while;

    return r;
END
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90546)

it works quite slow, to speed up process I suggest you to create new column `product_title_sorted`, run `update products set product_title_sorted=sv(product_title) where product_title_sorted is null`

and then use product_title_sorted in your queries

Comment: This is great, but I would I like to know, is this performance oriented?

Comment: No, it is slow approach

Comment: Oh! But thanks for the response and help @lashane. Thank you.. :)